# What is the possessive of "you guys"?

Tags: orthography, possessives, apostrophe

Most people seem to stumble over this. The problem can arise with any multi-word phrase that needs a possessive but ends in S, and so sounds awkward using the clitic apostrophe-S. I've heard this particular one variously rendered as:

- You guys'
- You guys's
- Your guys' / your guy's

What's you guys...your...guises...what's your take on it?

Comment: LOL at the last sentence, but I also think you just answered your own question. :)

Comment: Although "you guys'" is technically correct, it sounds awkward. It might be better to use "your".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regardless of the various permutations being thrown around these days, the *correct* possessive of *you guys* is **you guys’**, spoken or written, and I quote (emphasis mine):

> To form the possessive case of a plural noun ending in *s*, add **only** the apostrophe.
>
> EXAMPLES
>
> - highways’ intersection
> - the beetles’ legs
>
> ---
>
> <sup>John E. Warriner, *Warriner's English Grammar and Composition* (Orlando, FL: Harcourt Brace Jovanovich, 1986), 243</sup>

Since *you guys* is a plural noun, it is subject to the above rule, which has no exception, as far as I know.

Indeed, *you guys's* is not an uncommon colloqiualism (I have even used it myself on occasion) but it is grammatically incorrect, and thus has no place in standard, proper or formal contexts, whether spoken or written.

Comment: Just to throw a wrench into the mix, "you guys" **can** be singular, with the plural form being (of course) "youse guys."

Comment: “Correct”? Warriner is the guide to correct usage? _You guys_ is colloquial anyway; it doesn't necessarily follow the orthographic conventions prescribed in a literary standard. I would spell it _your guys’s_ if I were trying to convey the prounciation [jur gaɪzɪz].

Comment: Isn't the second person plural and singular now "you"? From what I understand, the term "you guys" is an informal grammatical error.

Comment: Ah but is it a noun or is it a pronoun? Possessive pronouns never use apostrophes.

Answer (score 3):

*You guys'* is correct written, pronounced *you guys's*.  (Dropping the *s* on the written version because *guys* is a plural, *not* because I think it should always be dropped if the word ends in an *s*.)  *You* rather than *your* because *you guys* is a unit and the possessive case doesn't need to be commuted across each element of it.

Comment: The pronunciation *you guys's* is incorrect, in my opinion. Would you really say "the boys's toys", for instance?!

Comment: @Jimi Oke: I certainly would, if the alternative is saying something aurally indistinguishable from the clearly incorrect "the boys toys".

Comment: ... so you're saying that, to avoid saying something correct ("the boys' toys") that happens to sound identical to something ungrammatical ("the boys toys"), you'd say something equally ungrammatical ("the boys's toys")? You're entitled to do so, I suppose, but I reserve my right to find it strange :-)

Comment: No, a bare apostrophe is never pronounced as anything. [If you say an extra "uhz" at the end, you must write apostrophe plus s, never a lone apostrophe](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/79083/2085).

Answer (score 2):

If a multi-word phrase takes a possessive, you can add *’s* to the whole thing:

- *The King of France’s crown*
- *The boy she likes’s books*

Constructions like this are unlikely to occur in formal or written English. Some speakers may not pronounce the extra *’s*, in which case it could be written with just an apostrophe.

In the case of *you guys*, it’s hard to tell: the word is colloquial (and regional), and there aren’t easily available sources describing the usage of the possessive. *Your guys’* and *your guys’s* seem to both be “acceptable” (i.e. used normally by native speakers) in the greater Philadelphia area; *you guys’* and *you guys’s* might be common elsewhere, but they sound a bit strange to me. (In Philadelphia proper, *youse guys’* is probably used too!)

Since *you guys* is colloquial, if you’re writing down the possessive of the word, you should use a spelling that reflects its pronunciation. If you’re wondering what to use in conversation, the answer is whatever you’ve been using all along. (I probably use *your guys’* and *your guys’s* most of the time.)

Comment: I’ve always found _your guys’_ quite bizarre. My guys’? I don’t own any guys (that I know of, at least). It’s like treating _you guys_ as a transparent collocation of pronoun and noun, but then giving it a possessive form that doesn’t fit with how pronouns and nouns collocate in this manner after all! After all, nobody—to my knowledge—would say that the possessive of _you people_ and _you children_ is _your people’s_ and _your children’s_. To me, _you guys_ is simply a single pronominal unit with a plural /z/, and it therefore has no morphological possessive.

Comment: Well, that’s just bizarre and un-English! Interlexemic inflection … what is this, Finnish? ;-)

Comment: It is a single pronominal unit that happens to inflect in both its parts. Think of it like _bon mot_, which can be _bons mots_ in the plural.

Don’t worry about how it works; it just does :) It’s a pronoun, it can afford to act exceptionally.

Comment: Hmm, does it feel better to think of _your_ as the pronoun and _guys’_ as a particle implying plurality?

Comment: Mmmmnope, not really. Ah well. I’ll live. _Bons mots_ is fine, ’cause there’s a logical reason (albeit in a different language) for it. It’s similar to how in Danish, the possessive of _hvem_ “who” is more and more frequently _hvems_ “who’s” rather than _hvis_ “whose”, and then the phrase _Hvis er det?_ “Whose is this?” has the audacity to be quite unreasonably warped into _Hvemses er detses?_ “Who’s’s is this’s’s”, with no less than two double possessives tacked on—one of them to a word that has absolutely no business being in the possessive to begin with. Madness!

Answer (score 1):

"You guys" is very informal, so... I'd just say "Hey, you guys, your bikes just got run over by a steamroller".  And then turn around and run like hell in case they want to kill the messenger. ;-)

Seriously, I wouldn't even try to find possessive, since "You guys" is just a form of address.  What I mean is, it's just (my reading) a kind of "plural of dude" (okay, "dudes"... but do people say that?)

Comment: It's because English lacks a second person plural. It wasn't always the case - "you" was formerly second person plural ("thou" was second person singular). In the north you have "you guys"; in the south, we have "y'all".

Comment: @Chris B. Behrens: You Southern boys don't have a monopoly on 2nd person plural constructions other than "you guys". In some Northern locales the plural of *you* is *youse*. In the area around Pittsburgh, some people still say *yins* (presumably short for *you'uns*). The rest of us realize that the 2nd person plural is, in fact, *you*.

Comment: 'Yins' is a new one on me.

Comment: My Irish friend says "ye" for 2nd person plural, which I feel is the most historically apt.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct usage is "youse guyses", though American English spellers may substitute the "s" for a "z".

Comment: Do you mean to say that you would indicate both terms with the possessive (that is, something like "you's guys' ")? Isn't it slightly too much?

Comment: @Paola Language likes redundancy! Latin, for instance, lets case, gender and number be marked on a whole row of words within a phrase—and the number of a subject additionally on the verb!